# BLToolkit + T4 generation + PostgreSQL database, possible?

Tags: postgresql, t4, bltoolkit, argumentnullexception

want to generate my data layer using [bltoolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.T4Templates.ashx), T4 templates and postgreSQL. I receive an exception running my T4 template, based on the one suggested by the [documentation](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.T4Templates.ashx):

```
Error 5 Running transformation: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: type, at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
(...)
```

Working in VSNET08, with all libraries referenced, connecting to mssql works ok, and at first, all seems correct, but i leave something...

This is my .tt template:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="True" #> 
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs"   #> 
<#@ include file="BLToolkit.ttinclude" #> 
<#@ include file="PostgreSQL.ttinclude"    #> 
<#@ include file="PluralSingular.ttinclude" #> 
<# 
  ConnectionString = "<connection string to postgresql database"; 
  DataProviderAssembly = @"..\References\Npgsql.dll"; 
  GenerateModel(); 
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely T4 can't find Npgsql.dll. When T4 is running, the current directory is not your project location. So you should try full path.

Another problem is depended assemblies. Add the following to your template:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"...PostgreSqlLocation...\Mono.Security.dll");
```

Comment: Solved updating Postgresql .Net driver. T4 is a great tool, but sometimes is difficult to get detailed error info...